# Adding an array of values to my chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to add values ("my_values") to my chart from a given array of values.

```
window.onload = f;

function f() {
    var my_values = [5, 8, 22, 6, 11];

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Number', 'Value'],
            [1, 12],
            [2, 12]
            /*
            I need to add an array "my_values" in a way presented below.
            [3, 5],
            [4, 8],
            [5, 22],
            [6, 6],
            [7, 11]
            */
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Title',
            hAxis: {title: 'X', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
            vAxis: {title: 'Y', minValue: 0, maxValue: 2400},
            fontSize: '18',
            legend: 'none',
            pointSize: 2.5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

}

My problem is that those values should be arrays ( [index, value] ). If i create an array of array, then my code is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
window.onload = f;

function f() {
    var chartData = [['Number', 'Value'],[1, 12],[2, 12]];
    var my_values = [5, 8, 22, 6, 11];
    var index = chartData.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < my_values.length; i++){
        chartData.push([index++, my_values[i]]);
    }

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Title',
            hAxis: {title: 'X', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
            vAxis: {title: 'Y', minValue: 0, maxValue: 2400},
            fontSize: '18',
            legend: 'none',
            pointSize: 2.5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do

```
    var counter = original.length
    var addThese = []

    for(var i = 0; i < my_values.length; i++){
        addThese.push([counter+1,my_values[i]])
        counter++
    } 
    original = original.concat(addThese)
```